# No Rows in Artifactory PostgreSQL Database

Tags: artifactory

I'm deploying Artifactory into an EKS cluster using the JFrog Helm chart [here](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/artifactory).  I am using PostgreSQL as the database and plan on following their production recommendation to use an externally deployed database instance.  I've deployed the Helm chart using both the internal PostgreSQL database as well an externally deployed database and both times successfully am able to launch Artifactory and upload packages.  However, when I connect to the actual PostgreSQL database in either case I am not able to query the relevant tables for the data I'd expect.  For example if I create groups or users in the Artifactory UI, I don't see any resulting rows in the database tables.  I tried to validate that I had the Helm values configured correctly by providing the Helm chart with an incorrect database username/password and the chart failed to apply so in my mind that implies that it is at least connecting to the correct PostgreSQL database.  I also see the correct schema deployed into PostgreSQL.

I am installing the Helm chart using the Terraform Helm provider and here is the templated values.yaml file:

```yaml
nginx:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-source-ranges: "0.0.0.0/0"

postgresql:
  enabled: false

database:
  type: postgresql
  driver: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: "jdbc:postgresql://${db_host}:${db_port}/artifactory"
  user: ${db_user}
  password: ${db_password}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to JFrog support, it turns out that I was looking at the incorrect database tables.  User information is stored in the `access_users` table and group information in `access_groups`, not `users` and `groups`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the complete helm install command as well as the values.yaml? Also, as you said you were able to bring up Artifactory using the Postgres DB, can you confirm while starting the Artifactory, Artifactory is actually hitting the correct DB? You can refer to the below connection URL log entry in your artifactory.log file,

2020-07-16 09:51:13,783 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:520) - Artifactory application context set to NOT READY by refresh
2020-07-16 09:51:28,884 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.d.DbServiceImpl:282) - Database: PostgreSQL 10.13 (Ubuntu 10.13-1.pgdg18.04+1). Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.5 Pool: postgresql
2020-07-16 09:51:28,893 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.d.DbServiceImpl:285) - **Connection URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/artifactory**
2020-07-16 09:51:28,899 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.d.DbServiceImpl:119) - ***Creating database schema***
2020-07-16 09:51:29,769 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.d.DbServiceImpl:126) - ***Database schema created***
2020-07-16 09:51:35,383 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.e.p.s.NodeEventPrioritiesStorageServiceFactory:27) - Initializing DB-based Priorities Storage Service

If it is hitting the correct DB, how exactly you are trying to fetch the tables data?

Comment: I am installing via the Terraform Helm provider so the values.yaml is templated and filled out on Terraform apply.  I've edited the above question with that info.

Comment: I'm not seeing exactly the logs you posted but do see the connection and schema initialized and the DB connection URL is correct.

I am trying to manually check the PostgreSQL database using pgAdmin

https://www.pgadmin.org/